# What type is the input data in SPOJ for python? and how can I implement it in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to programming and I've been trying to do problems in SPOJ.
I first solve them in a jupyter notebook to test them, and then copy the code.
This has costs me a lot of tries with errors.
I think SPOJ inputs are in stdin form, which I think I know how to "read".
However, if I want to try other inputs to test my code, what type of input should I use? lists?

Or how could I implement this stdin in jupyter?

Or how do you recommend I write my code tests before submitting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the specific problem. If you use python `input()` or `raw_input()`, you'll get the inputs as a string.

You need to typecast to the proper data type (int, float, str, etc.)

You should be able to test your code with the same input format as the problem statement.

For example:

this is the solution for problem `HYPNOS`:

https://www.spoj.com/problems/HPYNOS/

```
n=raw_input()
count=0
while True:
    sq=0
    for i in n:
    sq+=int(i)**2
    count+=1
    n=str(sq)

    if len(n)==1:
        if int(n)==1:
            print count
            break
    else:
       print "-1"
       break
```

Here, to test on custom inputs, you have to repeatedly input multiple integers as input in the terminal/jupyter notebook.

If you want to parse a list of test cases at a time.

Write a `solution()` function, which takes an input and returns the answer.

Keep a `mode` varuable, if `mode == "test"`, then pass a test set list, else just do the regular inputs and print solution.

Comment: Ok, so if the problem states that the input will be numbers, for example in the divsum problem (first number is the number of test cases, then the test cases numbers per se) they just put for example:
input:
3
100
9989
20

this will always be a list right? if I use stdin it should take it as a list, then as you said I make them the proper variable type. Or should I still treat them as string inputs, then convert?

Comment: they will be given through stdin, with python input() they will be str by default so you need to convert.